# Can't install MMFashion on Python

Tags: python

I am trying to install mmfashion on python but I am getting below error. Can you help me?

[MMFashion](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmfashion)

```
Compiling ./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.pyx because it depends on c:\users\username\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-odf3sfl0\mmcv-1.1.6\.eggs\cython-0.29.21-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd.
[1/1] Cythonizing ./mmcv/video/optflow_warp/flow_warp_module.pyx
C:\Anaconda3\envs\py365\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py:274: UserWarning: Error checking compiler version for cl: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
  warnings.warn('Error checking compiler version for {}: {}'.format(compiler, error))
error: [WinError 5] Access Denied: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-odf3sfl0\\mmcv-1.1.6\\.eggs\\Cython-0.29.21-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\\Cython\\Compiler\\FlowControl.cp36-win_amd64.pyd'
```

System;

```
Python version: ['3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 16:13:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]']
system: Windows
machine: AMD64
platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
uname: uname_result(system='Windows', node='DESKTOP-EIOK5V4', release='10', version='10.0.19041', machine='AMD64', processor='AMD64 Family 23 Model 113 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD')
version: 10.0.19041
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a file system permission error (`Access Denied`) when the installer tries to write to `C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\easy_install-odf3sfl0\\mmcv-1.1.6\\.eggs\\Cython-0.29.21-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\\Cython\\Compiler\\FlowControl.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`

You need to make this path writable to the user running the installer.

Comment: It is already writable and I am using admin account :/

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions mentioned in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7033? I.e. disabling Symantec Endpoint Protection, or doing `pip download foo_pkg, pip install foo_pkg.whl`.

Comment: I have tried after your comment but neither works for me.